# Как вытянуть всю аппаратную информцию с сервера через PHP?

Tags: php, linux

Как вытянуть всю аппаратную информцию с сервера через PHP при условии что shell для пользователя хостинга заблокирован?

Answer (score 1):

В директории, где будет файл **task.php** создаёшь файл **php.ini**. В нём пишешь одну строчку:

```
disable_functions=""
```

Далее в **task.php** делаешь **echo** всех системных функций, что надо. (*show_source, system, shell_exec, passthru, exec, popen, proc_open, allow_url_fopen*). Дальше как повезёт.